# Smart contract function not returning expected output

Tags: solidity, javascript, react

I'm quite new at this and I'm learning both Solidity, Javascript and React to play around with smart contracts. My contract ran well in Remix and in a local test net. I ran a bunch of tests using Mocha and everything went well.

My problem lies when I'm trying to fetch data using a .call() function. This is the code in the React/Javascript part (callback function from a button):

```
checkAccount = async () => {
   const data = await tacosavings.methods.getAccount().call();
   const { 0: money, 1: timeLeft } = data;

   this.setState({
      message: `Your account data -> 
      Tacos: ${web3.utils.fromWei(money, 'ether')} ether - 
      Timelock left: ${timeLeft} seconds`,
   });
};
```

In my smart contract the function goes like this (accountExists is a modifier but not relevant to this I think):

```
    function getAccount() external view accountExists returns (uint256, uint256) {
        if (accountData[msg.sender].timeLock < now) {
            uint256 timeRemaining = 0;
        } else {
            timeRemaining = accountData[msg.sender].timeLock - now;
        }
        return (accountData[msg.sender].savings, timeRemaining);
    }
```

The problem lies in that in Remix my return value makes sense, but in React either as a console log or in the "website" its a non-sense value:

> Your account data -> Tacos: 3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331.534351508065746944 ether - Timelock left: 862718293348820473429344482784628181556388621521298319395315527974912 seconds

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance =)!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to specify in the call method the account from I was sending the transaction from.

```
   checkAccount = async () => {
   const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
   const data = await tacosavings.methods.getAccount().call({
       from: accounts[0]
   });
   const { 0: money, 1: timeLeft } = data;

   this.setState({
       message: `Your account data -> 
       Tacos: ${web3.utils.fromWei(money, 'ether')} ether - 
       Timelock left: ${timeLeft} seconds`,
   });
};
```